# Rewrite rule not trying to redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have this 301 redirect rule for Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^park.php?park_id=3       http://hiking.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/park.php?park_id=3 [R=301,L]
```

I am trying to get this url:

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/park.php?park_id=3

to redirect to this url:

http://hiking.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/park.php?park_id=3

But as I have it now, it isn't trying to redirect.  The .htaccess file with the rule is located in the /parks/ directory.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Seems like this should be relatively straight forward.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try something like ^.*park.php?park_id=3 ? Probably your URI is still "outdoors/parks/park.php?park_id=3" even though your .htaccess file is inside the parks folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the query string; you need to add a conditional to be able to pick up on it, something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^park_id=3$
RewriteRule ^park.php http://hiking.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/park.php?park_id=3 [R=301,L]
```

That works when I mung it into an .htaccess on my localhost anyway.

It might be better to eventually, since it's RegExp pattern matching to do something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^park_id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^park.php http://hiking.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/park.php?park_id=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Which will pick up the integer at the end of the address and pass it to the new address (it's actually easier if you don't have a query string in the original address of course).